# Can't edit certain multilinestring lines of my GeoJSON file with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, json

I'm using GeoPandas, Python 3.7.

My job would be to edit a GeoJSON file, which contains reference lines, which are off by 30 centimeters + on the x axis.

My file looks like this:
[image]

I have to move the ref_lines -30 centimeters on the x axis.

I can't figure it out.

I have made a copy of it, transformed it to **epsg:32634**, also made a copy of the ref_lines and I've tried moving that with **.translate()**. This works, but in that geoseries I lose my header and all the other columns too.

The final JSON file would have to include everything, but with the ref_lines fixed and in (the original) **EPSG:4326** format.

My file currently looks like this:

```
def moving_ref_lines(gdf):
    transform = gdf.copy()
    transform = transform.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32634'})
    #Geoseries containing the fixed ref_lines
    ref_lines=transform[transform['type'] == 'ref_line']
    ref_lines_translated=ref_lines.translate(-0.3)
    others=transform[transform['type'] != 'ref_line']
    #ref_lines.merge(transform[transform['type'] != 'ref_line'])
    print("-------")
    print(ref_lines)#.translate(-0.3))
    print("-------")
    print(ref_lines_translated)
    #print(gdf)
    #ref_lines=ref_lines.append(transform['type'] != 'ref_line')
    
            
            
moving_ref_lines(gdf)
```

The output:

```
-------
    id      type                                           geometry
14   1  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((351937.093 5265740.945, 3519...
15   2  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((352029.336 5265704.023, 3520...
16   3  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((351929.480 5265727.600, 3519...
17   4  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((351984.352 5265663.332, 3519...
18   6  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((352072.636 5265564.225, 3520...
19   7  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((352279.001 5265648.278, 3522...
20   8  ref_line  MULTILINESTRING ((351998.543 5265710.342, 3519...
-------
14    MULTILINESTRING ((351936.793 5265740.945, 3519...
15    MULTILINESTRING ((352029.036 5265704.023, 3520...
16    MULTILINESTRING ((351929.180 5265727.600, 3519...
17    MULTILINESTRING ((351984.052 5265663.332, 3519...
18    MULTILINESTRING ((352072.336 5265564.225, 3520...
19    MULTILINESTRING ((352278.701 5265648.278, 3522...
20    MULTILINESTRING ((351998.243 5265710.342, 3519...
dtype: geometry
```

Answer (score 0):

The translate method returns a GeoSeries, which you must insert back into the geometry column of the GeoDataFrame. Try this:

```
def moving_ref_lines(gdf):
    transform = gdf.copy()
    transform = transform.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32634'})
    #Geoseries containing the fixed ref_lines
    ref_lines=transform[transform['type'] == 'ref_line']
    ref_lines['geometry']=ref_lines.translate(-0.3)
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, that helped!

How do I go on though? 
How can I join 2 DataSeries correctly? When I try merging them, the second one keeps the header too. 

Also I get an error after pasting your code, what does that mean? 

Sorry for the dumb questions, I really am a beginner. :)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\38python\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead